# Upvotes on questions but no answer

Tags: discussion, bounties, up-votes, views

I have come across this a few times. I post a question and get at least a couple of up votes on the question but no answers. And then slowly the question disappears in the big ocean of questions that all the sites on Stack Exchange gets. The only option to bring it back to life is to assign bounty for it and that is possible only after 2 days.

What happens in the meantime? Is there any ways to attract more views? Generally SO is my fallback option when I have failed all possible attempts to solve a problem or gain enough information about something. I have seen the question die down and even not be viewed as much as I would like. Is it because the question is lacking quality ?

**EDIT:**

Should I put this question in different words? Assuming up votes meaning others are interested in the question too or that the question deserved credit for something, if the question has no answers, is it poorly framed ?  Especially in cases when the user (mostly me) is trying to get answers for some problem that I face trying to do something that is very common and by common I mean  everyone would at some point of time attempt to do it or have done it in their programming career.

Comment: I understand this maybe treated as a duplicate, but what happens when I have no updates on my tries. In the sense, that I have tried everything I knew, everything I could find and all that is already in the question. i have no other leads on what to try or where to even start trying

Comment: At the end of the day there are [real people](http://imgur.com/tPDyRdh.jpg) on the other side of the screen with their day-to-day lives continuing. Short of knocking on their doors and pleading there is not much more that you can do.

Comment: @Lix: That is a very valid point. I try to be proactive on SO but find myself distracted by my regular life. I was looking for ways to start knocking on everyone's door and look for answers since that is my only way out.

Comment: @Ron you have sufficient rep to offer a bounty, so that is an option.  And sometimes, you can drop into chat and see if someone is willing to offer feedback on your post (tell you if they think something is wrong with your post and what you might do to improve it).  However, anytime you try to attract attention, you open yourself up to downvotes due to the extra views if someone finds something wrong with it.

Comment: I am not sure if the duplicate question answers my problem. The suggestions on the answers are still liable to die off soon. I have assigned bounty to a question and see it go unanswered. With limited reputation scores that I have its not possible to assign a high bounty on questions

Comment: @Ron I wouldn't necessarily assume that the fact you have an upvote means someone else wants an answer.  However, in general, if you ask a question that is closed as a duplicate which doesn't answer your post, it is often best to edit the question to explain why it isn't a duplicate (or why the answers didn't help you).

Comment: @psubsee2003: Thank you for the explanation. I have been in situations where I have no clue as what to do on the question and also tired assigning a bounty to the question and see it expire with no answer. There are situations when I hit a road block and do not know where to proceed. That leave me with no chance of 'bumping' my question since I have no new developments